# JQGrid: Dropdown, select the value, through addrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jqgrid

In JQGrid I have used the dropdown column with the following code (in colModel):

```
{
    name: 'CountryList', index: 'CountryList', width: 120, resizable: true, 
    sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', 
    formatoptions: { 
        disabled: false 
    },
    editoptions: {
        size    : 1,
        dataUrl : 'GetLists.ashx?Type=CountrLists&RegionID=2'),
        dataEvents: [{
            type: 'change',
            fn: function (e) {
                //$('input#Job_Number').val(this.value);
                //alert(this.value);
            }
        }],
        style: "width: 95%"
    }
},
```

**Problem**:

When adding row (**addrow**), i want the added row to have the above mentioned dropdown column value **selected**, by passing a paramter (preferably value of select/option HTML control)

```
parameters =
    {
    rowID   : undefined,
    initdata: { 
        chkSave: "false", 'Label': 'test', people: 'Test person', 
        CountryList: '2', Notes: 'Test notes.' 
    },
    position: "first",
    useDefValues: true,
    useFormatter: false,
    addRowParams: { extraparam: {} }
};


$("#tbJQGrid").jqGrid('addRow', parameters);
```

Please provide some solution or alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this,used the "setColProp" property to modify the dataUrl:

```
$("#tbJQGrid").setColProp('CountryList', { editoptions: { dataUrl: 'GetLists.ashx?Type=CountrLists&RegionID=15' } });
```

Hope this helps.

Kindly add to the comments, in case better solution exist.